# Alternative to Option or Command for Emulate 3 Button Mouse?

Tags: shortcut

As far as I can tell you you can either use Option or Command (OSKey) to emulate a 3rd mouse button. Both of these options, however, nuke important functions. Any work around for this?
I saw that some people are re-assigning the lost shortcuts, but I'm new to blender and I'm unsure how many I would have to re-assign nor what to re-assign them as. I would much prefer making my own custom shortcut modifier to use instead of option ( like shift+control or control+option). If there a way to do this? If not is there a list of common shortcuts that are not used by Blender already?
Blender 2.90.1
Thanks for your help!